# Local git on copied project

Tags: git

I had a previous project that I wanted to use as a starting point for a new project, I simply copied the entire folder as a starting point for the new project.

The issue is, now the new project has the git from the previous project. I want to remove git from the new project, in order to use a new git init.

However, I don't want to lose any code in the new project, or any git history from the old project.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the new copy, remove `.git/` directory, which only holds git metadata about the repo.  Then you can do a new `git init` in the new copy and all the same files will still be there.

Since files in .git are likely to be write-protected you may have to force deleteion with `rm -rf .git`.  Just make sure you're in the correct directory.

> However, I don't want to lose any code in the new project, or any git history from the old project.

make sure you're in the new copy directory and the old directory will be completely separate and untouched.

wouldn't hurt to make sure you're in sync with your remote also and all your branches are pushed, just as a backup.

Answer (score 2):

Create new directory for new project.

Copy all files from old project to new directory.

Remove .git folder in old project.

Init new git repo in new project via `$ git init`

Add all files from old project to new Git repo through

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

Push new git repo to remote repo (if any like github, azure etc)

This creates a new Git repo in your new proj, that does not have any Git history or metadata from the old proj, while also preserving code and history from old proj in new proj.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing sounds like a `clone` where there is no intention to ever push code back to the original project.

Start by cloning the repo:

```
git clone http://example.com/oldrepo.git newrepo
```

This will clone the project into a directory called `newrepo`.

Now you can 'disassociate' the new repo from the old one by removing any references to the upstream repository:

```
git remote remove origin
```

Finally, if you ever want to push to another (new) git repo in future, just add this instead:

```
git remote add origin https://example.com/newrepo
```

Comment: Ah yes, this is what I should have done before starting. Now doing damage control

Comment: So the first step here would eliminate this problem to begin with? Aka it creates a new local git?

Comment: I've just re-read your question and it isn't clear. When you say 'I don't want to lose any code in the new project, or any git history from the old project.' do you mean you want to keep the old history in the new project; or you just don't want to lose/affect any history from the old project? If it's the former, my answer is correct. If the latter then erik258 is right.